# Send To Unreal - custom collisions (UCX_) not importing properly

Tags: import, unreal-engine

I try to have a simple armature + meshes + collisions exported to unreal

I renamed my collisions with UCX_, then pipeline/Send To Unreal

- my meshes and collisions are merged together
- I still have to select all meshes/skeletons and add them to an actor

I expect the custom collision to be imported as physical objects and meshes to be imported..as meshes

are there any options in unreal before importing from blender ?

thanks for your help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is really old, but I found this, and your issue is that you are missing the full name.

It should be UCX_Arm_01_01, UCX_Arm_01_02, UCX_Arm_01_03